# "Two couple ducks" vs. "Two pairs of ducks"?

Tags: word-choice

What is more acceptable in English, if any?

> a) "In the background are two **pairs** of ducks"
>
> b) "In the background are two **couple** ducks"

Comment: You probably are aware of this, but in both _"two pairs of ducks"_ and _"two duck couples"_, there are four ducks total.  If you say _"In the background there are two **coupled** ducks."_  then there are only two ducks, and _**coupled**_ indicates that they are together.

Comment: I often find "couple" awkward when referring to generic sorts of pairs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Two pairs of ducks* is normal English, and it's a phrase that could be used to describe a situation like this one:

[image: Two pairs of ducks on the water]
<sup>Two pairs of ducks on the water</sup>

However, the word *couple* cannot be used in the same way as words like *dozen*, or *pair*. I might say *three dozen eggs* to describe 36 eggs, and I could say a picture like this shows *three pairs of shoes*:

[image: Three pairs of shoes on the carpet]
<sup>Three pairs of shoes on the carpet</sup>

We can use the word *a* with *couple* to describe two things; for example, *someone left a couple teddy bears on the chair,* or *someone left a couple drinks on the table:*

[image]

However, we do not used numbers such as *two* and *three* to describe *two couple of something*.

That said, we can use *couples* as a plural noun, and say, for example, *there are four couples on the lawn*:

[image]

but we would **not** say, <strike>there are four couple people on the lawn</strike>.

Comment: As a footnote, sometimes "a couple" can refer to "a small number, but not necessarily exactly two," as in, ["Someone left a couple nails on the workbench."](http://i.istockimg.com/file_thumbview_approve/2651236/3/stock-photo-2651236-workbench-with-hammer-and-nails.jpg) See [couple](http://www.onelook.com/?w=couple&ls=a) at OneLook.

Comment: Great answer with great examples. I would also add that "a couple **of** (things)" is equally acceptable as just "a couple (things)."

Comment: Beautiful and invested answer. Thank you.
I meant exactly to the first picture.